# Laravel: Consulta con WhereBetween

Tags: php, laravel-4

Quiero adaptar una consulta que tenía con un Where simple, usando un Where en conjunto con un Between, para hacer una consulta con un rango entre dos fechas. Mi código está así. Y estoy consciente que el "whereBetween" no está funcionando.

```
$consulta = DB::table('Empleados as E')
                    ->select(DB::raw('concat(E.nombre, " ", E.apellido_paterno," ", E.apellido_materno) as nombre'))
                    ->whereNotIn('E.id', function($query)
                    {
                        $min = '2016-08-01';
                        $max = '2016-08-08';
                        $query->select('Empleados_id')
                                    ->from('Entrada_regular as er')
                                    ->whereBetween('er.fecha',array($min, $max));
                    })
                    ->whereNotIn('E.id', function($query)
                    {
                        $min = '2016-08-01';
                        $max = '2016-08-08';
                        $query->select('Empleados_id')
                                    ->from('Entrada_tarde as et')
                                    ->whereBetween('et.fecha', array($min, $max));
                    })
                    ->get();
                return $consulta;
```

Necesito saber cómo meter un where con un between de la forma en que hago dicha consulta.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel?

Comment: Laravel versión 4.2

Comment: Hice una prueba rápida en Laravel 5.2 y me funciona sin problema.